# Consuming a xamarin template using a c# object, rather than explicitly passing it property values

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I'm fairly new to xamarin and I'm a little bit confused about how to consume a template using data from an object, rather than passing the xaml file all the template bindings.

What I have so far is a xaml file containing a contentView which has a control template. It also has an attached c# class which implements all the property bindings. (I can't share the code due to NDA reasons sadly)

So far the I am able to consume the template as such:

```
 <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <controls:AppointmentCardViewTemplate 
            ClientImage="testLogo.png"
            ClientName ="Mary Smith" 
            StartTime ="9:00am"
            EndTime ="10:00am"
            Details ="This is some text I am writing to fill in the space where details would normally go. This is because I want to test the functionality of the auto spacing when it consumes longer texts.">
            </controls:AppointmentCardViewTemplate>

            <controls:AppointmentCardViewTemplate 
            ClientImage="testLogo.png"
            ClientName ="Mary Smith" 
            StartTime ="9:00am"
            EndTime ="10:00am"
            Details ="This is some text I am writing to fill in the space where details would normally go. This is because I want to test the functionality of the auto spacing when it consumes longer texts.">
            </controls:AppointmentCardViewTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

However this is ultimately not useful as I want to fill this binding properties with some data from a client object, rather than explicitly defining the bindings with these placeholders.

The ultimate functionality what I want is that when I switch to the tab that displays the clients, the program would gather all the required clientData objects, and for each one, generate a frame using that data from the clientData object.

I've been trawling through both the microsoft docs and other tutorials but I haven't identified exactly how to achieve this. Rather than give me any sort of a solution, I was hoping somebody could point me towards either a tutorial that goes through this, or an example project I could cannibalize.

Additionally, I'd like to be able to click on a clients frame and it takes me through to a client's full page. What I'm struggling with here is how to associate a certain frame with the clientData object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> fill this binding properties with some data from a client object

In your case you could use **[BindableProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties)** .

#### in  AppointmentCardViewTemplate

Add the bindable property like following

```
public static readonly BindableProperty DetailProperty =
  BindableProperty.Create (
    "Detail", typeof(string), typeof(AppointmentCardViewTemplate), null, propertyChanged: OnDetailChanged);

public string Detail
{
  get { return (string)GetValue (DetailProperty); }
  set { SetValue (DetailProperty, value); }
}

static void OnDetailChanged (BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
  // it will be invoked when details changed , you can handle your logic here
}
```

Now you can binding the value of **Detail** to the property of **ContentPage** or **ViewModel**

```
<controls:AppointmentCardViewTemplate 
            ClientImage="testLogo.png"
            ClientName ="Mary Smith" 
            StartTime ="9:00am"
            EndTime ="10:00am"
            Details ="{Binding xxx}"> // xxx is a property in contentPage or ViewModel, you could set its value from other object dynamically in runtime .
</controls:AppointmentCardViewTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where you have "xxx", is that where I put the name of the property from my AppointmentCardViewTemplate template?

Comment: I haven't forgotten just yet. It hasn't fully solved my issue. In fact I've moved away from bindings altogether to get it working. Its not that your code is wrong, it just doesn't exactly achieve what I want. I'm putting together a more detailed sample project of what I want to do.

Comment: Does my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63990624/when-to-use-xamarin-bindings-as-opposed-to-passing-objects-to-page-constructors/63992061#63992061 solve your problem here ?